# Can't iterate throught repeatable element in web content manager in Liferay

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I've got a structure for my template for creating web content.
Parent element of text named List and it has got repeatable child element named Item.[image]

When I try to add two or more elements, I can't show them all with my template. It shows only first element of Item.
Here is my template

```
<#if Information.getSiblings()?has_content>
<#list Information.getSiblings() as information>
  <h1>${information.getChild('Title').getData()}</h1>
    <p>${information.getChild('Description').getData()}</p>
    <ul>
  <#list information.getChild('List').getSiblings() as item>
  <li>${item.getChild('Item').getData()}</li>
  </#list>
  </ul>
    </#list>
```

**UPD**
Deal with it. This is will display all items in list

```
<#if Information.getSiblings()?has_content>
<#list Information.getSiblings() as information>
  <h1>${information.getChild('Title').getData()}</h1>
    <p>${information.getChild('Description').getData()}</p>
    <ul>
  <#list information.getChild('List').getChild('Item').getSiblings() as item>
  <li>${item.getData()}</li>
  </#list>
  </ul>
    </#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should navigate the Information structure using `getChildren()` instead of `getSiblings()`

Something like

```
<#if parent.getChildren()?has_content>
    <#list parent.getChildren() as information>
        ...
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Using `getSiblings()` you are missig one of the "brothers"

Comment: thank for your answer. but i found solution. check updates!